# SpringBoot Conflict Database Configuration

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I want to create an MVC application with SpringBoot. When I start the home page is all ok, but when I ask my controller to get data from my database (configure with Hibernate) I have this error :
org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SessionHolder cannot be cast to org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerHolder.

I don't understand why SpringBoot tries to convert a Hibernate SessionHolder in a JPA SessionHolder.
My database configuration is :

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:/META-INF/database.properties")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class DatabaseConfig {
    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    // -- specifying destroyMethod="close" is not required. It's inferred by the
    // Spring container.
    @Bean(destroyMethod = "close")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("database.driverClassName"));
    dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("database.url"));
    dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("database.username"));
    dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("database.password"));
    return dataSource;
}

@Bean
public SessionFactory entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource) {
    LocalSessionFactoryBuilder builder = new LocalSessionFactoryBuilder(dataSource);
    // Packages Java to Scan
    String[] arrPackages = new String[] { "home" };
    builder.scanPackages(arrPackages);

    return builder.buildSessionFactory();
}


@Bean public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory sessionFactory) { 
    return new HibernateTransactionManager(sessionFactory); 
}
```

SpringBoot Application :

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = { 
        DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class,
        DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class, 
        HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class }
)

public class AppWeb {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AppWeb.class, args);
    }
}
```

POM File:

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>FrankGroup</groupId>
<artifactId>FrankArtifact</artifactId>
<version>0.1.0</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <hibernate.version>5.2.12.Final</hibernate.version>
    <mysql.version>5.1.18</mysql.version>
</properties>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>${mysql.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
        <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
        <version>3.18.2-GA</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>


<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

</project>
```

I believe that SpringBoot waits for a JPA configuration but I have set a Hibernate configuration, so how resolve this problem?

Log Error:
    2018-07-24 08:51:18.644 ERROR 15840 --- [nio-8081-exec-3] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet]      : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/tsat] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SessionHolder cannot be cast to org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerHolder] with root cause

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SessionHolder cannot be cast to org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerHolder
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.doGetTransactionalEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:203) ~[spring-orm-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:262) ~[spring-orm-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy89.createQuery(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.getQuery(SimpleJpaRepository.java:633) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:2.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.getQuery(SimpleJpaRepository.java:584) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:2.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:387) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:2.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:357) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:2.0.8.RELEASE]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:377) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:2.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:200) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:2.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:629) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:2.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:593) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:2.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:578) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:2.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:59) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:2.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:294) ~[spring-tx-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98) ~[spring-tx-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-tx-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:135) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:2.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:2.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy96.findAll(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at home.units.spittle.SpittleController.spittles(SpittleController.java:50) ~[classes/:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:877) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:783) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:974) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:866) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:851) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:496) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1468) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_161]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_161]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_161]
```

The hibernate.properties file :

```
hibernate.show_sql=true
hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings=false
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers=true
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=none
```

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38627491/spring-4-hibernate-5-org-springframework-orm-jpa-entitymanagerholder-cannot

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring 4 + Hibernate 5 = org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerHolder cannot be cast to org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SessionHolder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38627491/spring-4-hibernate-5-org-springframework-orm-jpa-entitymanagerholder-cannot)

Comment: I have that configuration (see the AppWeb  class) but the same error.

Comment: check your dependencies too - have you explicitly added any hibernate jars ?

Comment: Following your advise i have added to pom.xml the dependencies, but same error :               
    <dependency></br>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId></br>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId></br>
    </dependency></br>

    <dependency></br>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId></br>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId></br>
        <version>5.2.12.Final</version></br>
    </dependency> </br>

Comment: Can you please indicate in which packages are your \@SpringBootApplication and \@Configuration class?  Are they in the same package or at least \@Configuration in a sub-package?

Comment: the @SpringBootApplication is in the package > home and the \@Configuration class is in the > home.config

Comment: Ok.  Could you possibly provide a full stack trace of the case issue?

Comment: Hi. I have added the error log to the post.

Comment: Thanks that is a bit helpful.  Some have complained about a mix of Hibernate 4 and Hibernate 5 classes within the same project.  Do you have a hibernate.properties file present in your project?  If so, can you provide any settings you have present within hibernate.properties?

Comment: Ok i have added the  hibernate.properties content in the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution seems to leave the beans of sessionFactory and entityManagerFactory from @Configuration class (DatabaseConfig). 
SpringBoot build them automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure why you are getting this exact error.  First I would verify your imports to make sure everything is Hibernate 5 imports.  Last thing to check ,to make sure you don't have a mix of Hibernate 4 and Hibernate 5, double check your project dependencies to make sure there is no mix.

Then I would try changing your implementation to the following for your SessionFactory bean and your TransactionManager bean.  I suspect you are running into a situation where the SessionFactory created by the LocalSessionFactoryBuilder is not compatible with the EntityManagerFactory.  I do know there was recent work on the LocalSessionFactoryBean and HibernateTransactionManager to be usable by the EntityManagerFactory 
https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-17002.

Note imports:

```
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean;  
...
etc
```

SessionFactory bean:

```
@Bean(name = "sessionFactory")
public SessionFactory getSessionFactory(DataSource dataSource) throws Exception {

LocalSessionFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    factoryBean.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "home" });
    factoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);

    SessionFactory sf = factoryBean.getObject();
    return sf;
}
```

And TransactionManager

```
@Bean(name = "transactionManager")
public HibernateTransactionManager getTransactionManager(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager(sessionFactory);

    return transactionManager;
}
```

Then you should hopefully successfully be able to autowire the SessionFactory into your DAO/Repositories and get data from your database.

```
@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
```

Comment: Hi. Hibernate.version is 5.3.3.Final. My repository is public interface SpitterRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Spitter, Long> {
   //Spitter save(Spitter spitter);
   Spitter findByUsername(String username);
} .. Now the error is: Controller required a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found. Perhaps PagingAndSortingRepository works only with JPA ? Thanks.

Comment: Yes the Spring Data repositories need a JPATransactionManager and an entityManagerFactory.  You have a few options depending on what you are trying to accomplish.  1) Switch to JPA entirely 2) Add both JPA transaction manager and hibernate transaction manager and reference by name 3) Configure JPA transaction manager and unwrap hibernate session from JPA entity manager if you need to work with it directly.  Let me know which way you would like to go and I can provide assistance if needed.

Comment: The second solution seems the most smart :) Thanks

Comment: Do you need assistance or you have a good idea how to accomplish?

Comment: i could try it but if you have a fast solution is better :) Thanks